# python print unicode 'anomaly'

Tags: python, unicode

Im puzzled by the following:

```
>>> 
>>> a
'abc'
>>> z
u'xyz'
>>> print a,z
abc xyz
>>> print (a,z)
('abc', u'xyz')
>>> print [a,z]
['abc', u'xyz']
>>> print (a,str(z))
('abc', 'xyz')
```

What are the rules for when an implicit type conversion is done and when its not?

Comment: The difference is whether __repr__ or __str__ is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a difference between the `str` and the `repr` of a unicode object. The `repr` is intended to give an equivalent object if you paste it back into Python, and so it includes the `u`; the `str` is meant for human readability, and so it doesn't. The `str` and `repr` of strings are identical (they are just the same string).

The relevant rules here for which one is used are:

- Mentioning a variable at the interpreter prompt echoes back its `repr`
- `print` uses the `str`
- `print a,z` prints the two objects separated by a space - it parses as `print (a), (z)`. It uses the `str` of both
- `print(a, z)` builds, and prints, a tuple containing the two objects. `print [a,z]` behaves similarly, except it builds and prints a list instead. In both cases, `print` uses the `str` of the container - which for both a tuple and a list uses the `repr` of its contents.
- `print(a, str(z))` calls `str(z)` first, and puts its result in the tuple - and so the repr of *that string* gets used, rather than the repr of `z`.

Comment: oh i see, print doesnt recurse into a structure. thanks.  [this popped up while attempting to figure out what im getting from mutagen on id3 tags vs FLAC and some 'diagnostic' output to figure out if im getting strings or unicode]

Answer (score 0):

[`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) statement call [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) for arguments.

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> z = u'xyz'
>>> str(a)
'abc'
>>> str(z)
'xyz'
>>> print a, z
abc xyz
>>> print str(a), str(z)
abc xyz

>>> str((a,z))
"('abc', u'xyz')"
>>> str([a,z])
"['abc', u'xyz']"
>>> print (a,z)
('abc', u'xyz')
>>> print str((a,z))
('abc', u'xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 doesn't perform implicit type conversion except when adding a Unicode string (which are of the `unicode` type) to an bytes string (which are of the `str` type) (Python 3 doesn't do implicit type conversion ever). `str` converts an object to a bytes string (it's doing *explicit* conversion, **not**  *implicit* conversion).